# Обновление модели Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

Как можно организовать такую логику, чтобы на web-странице была возможность добавить(удалить/изменить) колонку определенного типа в sql таблицу, при этом чтобы динамически изменялась модель Entity Framework. Т.е. задача написать страницу для администратора, который с кодом работать не будет, и на этой странице можно редактировать таблицу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это невозможно в рантайме. Ваши Entity-классы содержат поля/свойства, соответствующие колонкам таблицы. Если в таблице добавится колонка, в Entity-классах прямо во время выполнения должны возникнуть поля? А если колонка исчезнет, что должно произойти с тем (скомпилированным!) кодом, который использует соответствующие им поля?

Цель Entity Framework, как и любой другой ORM — принести в мир баз данных контроль типов и безопасность, проверяющуюся во время компиляции. Для администрирования базы данных ORM — неподходящий инструмент.

Не пользуйтесь EF, для вашей задачи он не подходит.