# Динамическое добавление полей в БД (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, возник у меня вопрос по поводу добавления полей в таблицу БД, с помощью кода (например в админке сайта для товара).

Можно ли реализовать такой функционал, например для товара "Телефон" добавить поле год выпуска с той же админки?
Куда стоит двигаться с поиском ответа и примеров (возможно даже правильные поисковые запросы =))?

Стек технологий: C#(ASP.NET MVC + Entity Framework)

Спасибо всем за советы/ответы.

Comment: Двигаться стоит в обратную сторону от таких затей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Были уже на сайте похожие вопросы, из последнего что помню это:

- [Добавление полей сущности EF динамически](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486368/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-ef-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8)
- [Обновление модели Entity Framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419088/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-entity-framework)

EF не предназначен для этого, основная заточка -- под механизм миграций (не в рантайме).

Если хотите дополнительные поля в админке добавлять, то проектируйте в структуре базы дополнительные таблицы с описанием полей, их значений.

И уже в рантайме чтобы оставалось только вставлять в готовые таблицы.

Update: где-то я уже скидывал статью на хабр что всё-таки подобное делали, но не вижу где (вероятно кому-то в комментах оставил, а не ответом), вот ещё раз:

- [Roslyn & EF Core: конструируем DbContext в runtime](https://habr.com/ru/post/500102/)

Comment: А если не добавлять поле в саму сущность "Телефон", а например сделать в ней поле AdditionalInfo: string, в котором будет хранится JSON объект с дополнительными полями? Идея мне кажется так себе но все же.

Или другую таблицу с полями, но я не имею представления как ее правильно реализовать, а лютый **вно код писать не очень хочу =)

Comment: @BogdanStefanjuk В ссылке на дубликат кратко раскрывается подход EAV. А за любую универсальность приходится платить. Чем -- это уже вам выбирать. В EAV и JSON вы сознательно открываетесь от части функциональности БД -- индексов, триггеров, отказываясь от EF теряете удобные современные механизмы ORM... Выбор за вами.